# ¿Cómo obtener todos los datos antes o después de 10 días de intervalo?

Tags: php, mysqli

En la columna `date_post` tengo registro de fecha de los artículos en el siguiente formato `2020-01-17 14:09:24` estoy tratando de mostrar registros en la siguiente condición artículos que estén entre los últimos 10 días de la fecha de publicación pero al ejecutar la consulta no me muestra ningún resultado y, tampoco ningún error en la ejecución.

```
$active = 1;
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT
    title
    FROM news
    WHERE
    date_post >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
    AND
    active=?
    LIMIT
    10");

$stmt->bind_param("i",$active);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$stmt->bind_result($title);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $title;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener dichos registros correctamente?

Comment: No termino de entender el resultado que esperas, si pudieras editar y ser un poco mas clara te lo agradecería

Comment: Lo primero que te recomendaría sería simplificar el problema probando la consulta antes en el phpMyAdmiin, por ejemplo: ¿te has asegurado de que haya datos que cumplan esa condición? Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado que quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo.

Comment: La consulta en sí es correcta, pero puede que no haya datos que cumplan con ese criterio, o que la consulta no se esté ejecutando. En tu código no hay ningún control de errores. Por ejemplo, pudiste haberte equivocado escribiendo un nombre de tabla o columna. De todos modos, uno de los controles que faltan en tu código es verificar si esa consulta trae filas con `num_rows`. Por ejemplo: **`if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) { //Hay filas, procedemos a leer } else { echo "No se encontraron registros... o hacer otra cosa"; }`** Cuando programas debes prever todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando programas tienes que prever todas las eventualidades. En este código te puedo sacar al menos 3 eventualidades no cubiertas en tu código.

- ¿Hay conexión?
- ¿La consulta es correcta?
- ¿La consulta trae datos?

No puedes lanzar una consulta y pasar a leer datos si verificar lo que ha ocurrido.

Asumiendo que ya antes has comprobado las primeras dos eventualidades, te muestro un código donde controlamos la tercera:

```
$active = 1;
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT
    title
    FROM news
    WHERE
    date_post >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
    AND
    active=?
    LIMIT
    10");

$stmt->bind_param("i",$active);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($title);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $title;
    }
} else {
    echo "No se encontraron registros que cumplan el criterio"; 
}
```

Si las primeras dos no las has controlado, también deberías hacerlo. No hay que programar pensando que todo saldrá bien siempre. Hay que ser pesimistas programando, para que las cosas funcionen de manera óptima.